# Group and count the occurances using angular ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, datetime

I have this kind of data [image: Date Time Format]

How do I filter it and count it. The result that I'm trying to get is as follows:

Oct : 2
Nov : 3

This is the code that i have been trying

```
let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => item.date))
data.forEach((date)=>{
     this.resultData.push({
        date: date, 
        products: this.products.filter(i => i.date === date)
      })
})
```

should i just change to normal js for loop or using ts foreach loop?

Comment: FYI - ForEach is js mthod not just ts method. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)

Comment: use date.getMonth() to count which month the date belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove one of the loops when running `forEach` then later filtering, see below example

```js
const dates = [
  "2020-02-29T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-12-31T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-03-31T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-05-31T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-29T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-08-31T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-06-30T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2019-12-31T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-29T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-02-29T08:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-08-31T08:00:00.000Z"
];


const summary = dates.reduce((p, n) => {
  const d = new Date(n).toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
    month: 'short'
  })
  return ({ ...p, [d]: typeof p[d] !== 'undefined' ? p[d] + 1 : 1 })
}, {})

console.log(summary)
```